# How to stop HTML table from resizing row height based on cell contents

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm creating a table to display dart game scores. For some reason, even though I'm specifying row heights in pixels and table-display is set to fixed, it still resizes the row heights based on the cell contents. For example, if I change the font-size to something larger, the corresponding row get's higher.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the HTML for the table:

```css
 .scoreboard{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
table, th, tr, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center bottom;
  font-family: Verdana;
}
table tr {
  max-height: 25px;
}
.hdrRowHalf{
  height: 15px;
}
.pRowTop{
  height: 25px;
}
.pRowBot{
  height: 30px;
}
.pNumCol{
  width: 3%;
}
.pNameCol{
  width: 31%;
}
.playerCol{
  width: 37%;
}
.scoreCol{
  width: 22%;
}
.avgCol{
  width: 7%;
}
.throwCol{
  width: 9%;
}
.legsCol{
  width: 7%;
}
.pNum{
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
.pName{
  font-size: 70px;
}
.score{
  font-size: 70px;
  text-align: center;
}
.numThrows{
  font-size: 35px;
  text-align: center;
}
.throws{
  font-size: 35px;
  text-align: center;
}
.legs{
  font-size: 55px;
  text-align: center;
}
.avg{
  font-size: 35px;
  text-align: center;
}
.total{
  font-size: 45px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table class='scoreboard'>
  <tr class='hdrRowHalf'>
    <th rowspan='2' class='pNumCol'>#</th>
    <th rowspan='2' class='pNameCol'>Player</th>
    <th rowspan='2' class='scoreCol'>Score</th>
    <th class='avgCol hdrText'>THR</th>
    <th rowspan='2' class='throwCol'>1</th>
    <th rowspan='2' class='throwCol'>2</th>
    <th rowspan='2' class='throwCol'>3</th>
    <th rowspan='2' class='legsCol'>L</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class='hdrRowHalf'>
    <th class='avgCol'>AVG</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class='pRowTop'>
    <td rowspan='2' class='pNum'>1</td>
    <td id='p1n' rowspan='2' class='pName'>Aaron</td>
    <td id='p1s' rowspan='2' class='score'>501</td>
    <td id='p1nt' class='numThrows'>42</td>
    <td id='p1t1' class='throws'>T20</td>
    <td id='p1t2' class='throws'>D25</td>
    <td id='p1t3' class='throws'>7</td>
    <td id='p1l' rowspan='2' class='legs'>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='pRowBot'>
    <td id='p1a' class='avg'>120</td>
    <td id='p1t' colspan='3' class='total'>180</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='pRowTop'>
    <td rowspan='2' class='pNum'>2</td>
    <td id='p2n' rowspan='2' class='pName'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td id='p2s' rowspan='2' class='score'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td id='p2nt' class='numThrows'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td id='p2t1' class='throws'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td id='p2t2' class='throws'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td id='p2t3' class='throws'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td id='p2l' rowspan='2' class='legs'>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='pRowBot'>
    <td id='p2a' class='avg'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td id='p2t' colspan='3' class='total'>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='pRowTop'>
    <td rowspan='2' class='pNum'>3</td>
    <td id='p3n' rowspan='2' class='pName'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td id='p3s' rowspan='2' class='score'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td id='p3nt' class='numThrows'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td id='p3t1' class='throws'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td id='p3t2' class='throws'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td id='p3t3' class='throws'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td id='p3l' rowspan='2' class='legs'>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='pRowBot'>
    <td id='p3a' class='avg'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td id='p3t' colspan='3' class='total'>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='pRowTop'>
    <td rowspan='2' class='pNum'>4</td>
    <td id='p4n' rowspan='2' class='pName'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td id='p4s' rowspan='2' class='score'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td id='p4nt' class='numThrows'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td id='p4t1' class='throws'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td id='p4t2' class='throws'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td id='p4t3' class='throws'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td id='p4l' rowspan='2' class='legs'>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='pRowBot'>
    <td id='p4a' class='avg'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td id='p4t' colspan='3' class='total'>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I've tried using div containers and different display types, but nothing seems to work. Row height seems always to be dependent upon font-size.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to limit the height directly to `td` or `tr`. And `table-layout` refers to `width`, not `height`. To limit the height of a cell, wrap the content in a `div`:

```css
table {
  width: 200px;
}

table td {
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="table-height">
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi, recusandae.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div style="max-height:40px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi, recusandae.</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing might be related to the way you have set the max-height property in your CSS. The **max-height** property sets the maximum height of an element, but if the content inside the element exceeds this height, it will still expand.

In your case, you've set **max-height: 25px;** for the table tr, which means that the maximum height of each row should be **25 pixels**. However, if the content (like larger font size) exceeds this height, the row might expand.

To ensure fixed row heights, you should use height instead of **max-height**. Try changing this part of your CSS:

`table tr {max-height: 25px;}`
To
`table tr {height: 25px;}`

This change will apply a fixed height of 25 pixels to each row regardless of content. Adjust the values according to your design preferences.

Comment: Hi Jahid, thanks for the response. I tried that but the row heights are still changing depending on the text-size. (ETA: btw, I only added the "max-height" part while I was trying dozens of things to try to get it to work. With or without the max-height, it doesn't seem to have any effect on table layout)

Comment: You use too many font sizes in your code, So if you want to show all text in the same size, then use the same font-size for all.

Answer (score 0):

You add many font sizes in your code, move these, and use them as you need. See example-

```css
.scoreboard{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
table, th, tr, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center bottom;
  font-family: Verdana;
}
table tr {
  max-height: 25px;
}
.hdrRowHalf{
  height: 15px;
}
.pRowTop{
  height: 25px;
}
.pRowBot{
  height: 30px;
}
.pNumCol{
  width: 3%;
}
.pNameCol{
  width: 31%;
}
.playerCol{
  width: 37%;
}
.scoreCol{
  width: 22%;
}
.avgCol{
  width: 7%;
}
.throwCol{
  width: 9%;
}
.legsCol{
  width: 7%;
}
.pNum{
  text-align: center;
}
.pName{
}
.score{
  text-align: center;
}
.numThrows{
  text-align: center;
}
.throws{
  text-align: center;
}
.legs{
  text-align: center;
}
.avg{
  text-align: center;
}
.total{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table class='scoreboard'>
  <tr class='hdrRowHalf'>
    <th rowspan='2' class='pNumCol'>#</th>
    <th rowspan='2' class='pNameCol'>Player</th>
    <th rowspan='2' class='scoreCol'>Score</th>
    <th class='avgCol hdrText'>THR</th>
    <th rowspan='2' class='throwCol'>1</th>
    <th rowspan='2' class='throwCol'>2</th>
    <th rowspan='2' class='throwCol'>3</th>
    <th rowspan='2' class='legsCol'>L</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class='hdrRowHalf'>
    <th class='avgCol'>AVG</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class='pRowTop'>
    <td rowspan='2' class='pNum'>1</td>
    <td id='p1n' rowspan='2' class='pName'>Aaron</td>
    <td id='p1s' rowspan='2' class='score'>501</td>
    <td id='p1nt' class='numThrows'>42</td>
    <td id='p1t1' class='throws'>T20</td>
    <td id='p1t2' class='throws'>D25</td>
    <td id='p1t3' class='throws'>7</td>
    <td id='p1l' rowspan='2' class='legs'>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='pRowBot'>
    <td id='p1a' class='avg'>120</td>
    <td id='p1t' colspan='3' class='total'>180</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='pRowTop'>
    <td rowspan='2' class='pNum'>2</td>
    <td id='p2n' rowspan='2' class='pName'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td id='p2s' rowspan='2' class='score'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td id='p2nt' class='numThrows'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td id='p2t1' class='throws'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td id='p2t2' class='throws'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td id='p2t3' class='throws'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td id='p2l' rowspan='2' class='legs'>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='pRowBot'>
    <td id='p2a' class='avg'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td id='p2t' colspan='3' class='total'>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='pRowTop'>
    <td rowspan='2' class='pNum'>3</td>
    <td id='p3n' rowspan='2' class='pName'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td id='p3s' rowspan='2' class='score'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td id='p3nt' class='numThrows'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td id='p3t1' class='throws'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td id='p3t2' class='throws'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td id='p3t3' class='throws'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td id='p3l' rowspan='2' class='legs'>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='pRowBot'>
    <td id='p3a' class='avg'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td id='p3t' colspan='3' class='total'>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='pRowTop'>
    <td rowspan='2' class='pNum'>4</td>
    <td id='p4n' rowspan='2' class='pName'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td id='p4s' rowspan='2' class='score'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td id='p4nt' class='numThrows'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td id='p4t1' class='throws'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td id='p4t2' class='throws'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td id='p4t3' class='throws'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td id='p4l' rowspan='2' class='legs'>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='pRowBot'>
    <td id='p4a' class='avg'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td id='p4t' colspan='3' class='total'>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: OK, but the whole point is that I want fixed row height independent of font size. Reducing the number of different font sizes doesn't help. Thanks for the response, though.